# Convert the callback to async/await for nexmo.message.sendSms?

Tags: asynchronous, vonage

My nodejs app calls `nexmo` API to send SMS message. Here is the API:

```
nexmo.message.sendSms(sender, recipient, message, options, callback);
```

In the app, it is

```
const nexmo = new Nexmo({
                apiKey: "nexmoApiKey",
                apiSecret: "nexmoSecret"
            }, { debug: true });        

nexmo.message.sendSms(nexmo_sender_number, cell_country + to, message, {type: 'unicode'}, async (err, result) => {....});
```

Is there a way I can convert it to async/await structure like below:

```
const {err, result} = nexmo.message.sendSms(nexmo_sender_number, cell_country + to, vcode, {type: 'unicode'});
if (err) {.....};
//then process result...
```

I would like to return the `message` to parent function after the message was successfully sent out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nexmo-node` library only supports callbacks for now. You'll need to use something like `promisify` or `bluebird` to convert the sendSms function to promises, and the use async/await with it. Here is an example using Node's promisify

```
const util = require('util');
const Nexmo = require('nexmo');

const nexmo = new Nexmo({
                apiKey: "nexmoApiKey",
                apiSecret: "nexmoSecret"
            }, { debug: true });        


const sendSms = util.promisify(nexmo.message.sendSms);

async function sendingSms() {
  const {err, result} = await sendSms(nexmo_sender_number, cell_country + to, message, {type: 'unicode'});
  if (err) {...} else { 
    // do something with result 
  }

}
```

Comment: Since nexmo uses classes the this reference breaks in the solution above.
Can be solved by writing over the original function.

nexmo.message.sendSms = util.promisify(nexmo.message.sendSms)
async function sendSMS(tel, message) {
  return nexmo.message.sendSms('testing', tel, message, { type: 'unicode' })
}

Answer (score 0):

Though Alex's solution is elegant. It breaks TypeScript and util does some 'hidden logic' on the promises; when it errors stack traces are not clear.

This also allows you to stay true to the API and get auto-fill on the properties.

So instead you can do this **(TypeScript)**

```
/**
 * Return the verification id needed.
 */
export const sendSMSCode = async (phoneNumber: string): Promise<string> => {

    const result = await new Promise(async (resolve: (value: RequestResponse) => void, reject: (value: VerifyError) => void) => {
        await nexmo.verify.request({
            number: phoneNumber,
            brand: `${Config.productName}`,
            code_length: 4
        }, (err, result) => {
            console.log(err ? err : result)
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            resolve(result)

        });
    })

    return result.request_id
}
```